Album images are not rendering using react-native-tab-view
I'm using expo-media-library to show images in-app from the gallery of the user. Now, there are multiple albums in gallery and to show them in a tabbed form, I'm using react-native-tab-view. Issue is my images are not rendering on screen, i can see the tabs with album names on it, meaning, i'm getting the albums but the album assets (which are album images) are not being rendered.
Checked the docs and they have shown a static way of making routes with renderScene and SceneMap (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-view/) I'm trying to make a dynamic implementation of this such that for each album id, i can get that album's assets, but again i'm getting the albums but the images are not being rendered.
//image parameter here is the redux store for keeping the images that are selected by user so it shouldn't matter in our case


function AlbumTabs({ albums, image }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [sceneAssets, setSceneAssets] = useState();
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);

  const renderScene = () => {
    SceneMap(
      albums.reduce((scenes, album) => {
        scenes[album.id] = <AlbumEntry album={album} image={image} />;
        console.log("scenes: ", scenes);

        return scenes;
      }, {})
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("are we getting into render scene");
    // renderScene();

    const routeArray = albums.map((album) => {
      console.log("album.id: ", album.id);
      console.log("album.title: ", album.title);

      return {
        key: album.id,
        title: album.title,
      };
    });
    console.log("album length", albums.length);

    setRoutes(routeArray);
  }, [albums]);

  // useEffect

  return (
    // <View style={styles.tabViewContainer}>
    routes.length > 0 ? (
      <TabView
        renderTabBar={(props) => (
          <TabBar
            {...props}
            indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#EA9B3F" }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: 50 }}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            renderLabel={({ route, color }) => (
              <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 15, fontWeight: "500" }}>
                {route.title}
              </Text>
            )}
            
          />
        )}
        navigationState={{ index, routes }}
        renderScene={renderScene}
        onIndexChange={setIndex}
        initialLayout={initialLayout}
        lazy={true}
        style={styles.tabView}
      />
    ) : (
      <Text>Else body</Text>
    )

    // </View>
  );
}

// below component is supposed to render the images from a given album


function AlbumEntry({ album, image }) {
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image.value != undefined) {
      setSelectedImages(image.value);
    }
  }, [image]);

  async function getAlbumAssets() {
    // this is related to activity loader
    setLoading(true);
    const albumAssets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      album,
      first: 30,
    });
    setAssets(albumAssets.assets);
    // console.log("album assets on getAlbumAssets", albumAssets.assets);
    
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("album assets");
    getAlbumAssets();
  }, [album]);

  

  return (
    <View key={album.id} style={styles.albumContainer}>
      <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={styles.albumNameStyle}>
        {album.title}
      </Text>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#EA9B3F" />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.albumAssetsContainer}>
          {assets.length === 0 ? (
            <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={styles.noResultsText}>
              0 results
            </Text>
          ) : (
            assets &&
            assets.map((_image) => (
                <Image
                  style={[
                    styles.imageStyle,
                    image.value != undefined
                      ? image.value.some(
                          (_uri) => _image.uri == _uri.original
                        ) && styles.selectedImage
                      : {},
                  ]}
                  source={{ uri: _image.uri }}
                  width={100}
                  height={100}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))
          )}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

Any help is greatly appreciated!
